# ¿En qué situaciones se usa "antes de que" y "después de que"?

Tags: conjunciones

Me gustaría saber si es correcto lo que tengo entendido:

- *Antes de que* expresa posterioridad
- *Después de que* expresa anterioridad

¿Verdad?

Por ejemplo:

> 1. *Acabábamos con esta batalla antes que se pusiera el sol.*
> 2. *Acabábamos con esta batalla después de que se hubiera puesto el sol.*

Comment: Siempre depende del punto de vista.  *después de que* introduce una cláusula que ocurre anteriormente a la principal, pero la principal ocurre posteriormente a la subordinada. Por cierto, yo habría usado el indicativo en el segundo ejemplo, ya que al momento de acabar la batalla, ya había puesto el sol por lo que representa un hecho acaecido.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con guifa. Se acostumbra bastante a usar tanto indicativo como subjuntivo en expresiones como *antes/después + de que + indicativo/subjuntivo.* La elección, dependerá bastante del contexto. Por ejemplo: *después de que te **llamé*** (la acción se llevó acabo) / *después de que te **llamara*** (esto es lo que debió haber sucedido, no se sabe si ocurrió o no)

Comment: @guifa Según la RAE, el punto de referencia es la cláusula principal, decisión que mantiene la relación lógica entre *antes (de) que* y *anterioridad*. Hay un link en mi respuesta.

Comment: +1 a @fedorqui. Fue acertado abrir este bounty, hay buenas respuestas.

Comment: @Rodrigo gracias. Si es que con el nivel que hay aquí, ¡abrir un bounty es garantía de éxito! Luego lo complicado es saber a quién dárselo :)

Answer (score 6):

Aunque es cierto que la respuesta depende del punto de vista, la descripción del sistema gramatical de una lengua tiene un importante componente convencional que suele eliminar el problema del punto de vista. En este caso, la [NGLE](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=bMfaylmZyYPbYkvg) (*Nueva gramática de la lengua española*) es categórica (énfasis añadido):

> Como las nociones de 'anterioridad' y 'posterioridad' son relacionales, es importante precisar en qué sentido se emplean. Nótese que la acción expresada por el predicado principal (*nos iremos*) es posterior a la que expresa *cuando llegues* en *Cuando llegues, nos iremos*. Sin embargo, la paráfrasis que admite esta última oración es *después de que llegue*, no *antes de que llegues*. **Se entenderá aquí de forma convencional que se obtiene la interpretación de posterioridad cuando se admiten paráfrasis de posterioridad ('después, una vez que'), no cuando el punto temporal designado sea posterior a otro**. Ciertamente, el punto designado por *cuando llegues* en *Cuando llegues, nos iremos* es anterior a la acción de irse. De manera análoga, en *Cuando recorrió diez kilómetros, se detuvo*, se dice que la acción de detenerse tiene lugar después de realizado cierto recorrido, por lo que se obtiene también la interpretación de posterioridad (en el sentido que se ha dado a esta noción) en la oración de *cuando*. Es lógico que la permutación de los sucesos altere el orden en el que tienen lugar:
>
> - Cuando se mareó, se cayó (el mareo precede a la caída) ~ Cuando se cayó, se mareó (la caída precede al mareo);
> - Cuando oyó la música, salió a la calle ~ Cuando salió a la calle, oyó la música, etc.

RAE explicita que "después (de que)" y "una vez que" indican **posterioridad**, con lo que "antes (de que)" debe indicar **anterioridad**. Es verdad que esto es relativo, pero lo que se suele tomar como referencia es la acción de la principal, no de la subordinada.

Como en tu caso la acción de acabar la batalla en el primer caso ocurre **antes** de que se ponga el sol, *antes de que* indica **anterioridad**. Como en el segundo caso la acción de acabar la batalla ocurre **después** de que se ponga el sol, *después de que* indica **posterioridad**

Answer (score 3):

La frase:

> Acabábamos con esta batalla antes que se pusiera el sol.

Significa que la primera acción (la batalla) la terminaban antes de que ocurriera la segunda acción (la puesta del Sol). Quiere decir que "*antes de que*" refleja **anterioridad**.

En cuanto a la frase:

> Acabábamos con esta batalla después de que se hubiera puesto el Sol.

Significa que la batalla la terminaban después de que hubiera ocurrido la puesta del sol, por tanto; la frase "*después de que*" indica **posterioridad**.

Answer (score 2):

No tengo claro lo que se pregunta; estas expresiones denotan anterioridad o posterioridad dependiendo del punto de vista. Así:

> Acabábamos con esta batalla antes que se pusiera el sol.

Indica que cuando se puso el sol ya habíamos acabado con la batalla. Es decir: la puesta del sol se produce posteriormente al final de la batalla. Y la construcción *después de que* es la simétrica:

> Acabábamos con esta batalla después de que se hubiera puesto el sol.

Primero se puso el sol y luego acabamos con la batalla.

En cuanto a la corrección de las expresiones *antes de que* / *antes que*, depende de la zona. En España lo más habitual es *antes de que*, pues aquí se usa *de* en todos los casos en que se usaría de no existir oración subordinada:

> antes de que se pusiera el sol / antes de ponerse el sol

Pero en otros países hispanohablantes lo habitual es no usar el *de*. Esto llevó a que en España se criticara el supuesto error gramatical en el título de la película *Antes que anochezca*, sobre la vida del poeta cubano Reinaldo Arenas, sin darse cuenta de que este título se había tomado de la autobiografía del poeta, quien utilizó en él la construcción habitual en Cuba.

Comment: Sí, la pregunta es algo confusa. Desde el momento que su autor no está registrado, creo que se puede reinterpretar de forma genérica. Por ello, una buena respuesta puede describir con generalidad el uso de _antes de que_ y _después de que_ para ser usada como referencia.

Comment: Me costó mucho decidir a quién entregar el bounty. Finalmente opté por la respuesta de Yay por su contenido teórico. Sin embargo, un 49% de él te lo paso moralmente a ti, pues el redactado es muy claro y útil. ¡Gracias Gorpik por tan buenas aportaciones!

Comment: @fedorqui Yo también he votado por la respuesta de Yay :) Creo que es más completa que la mía.